# Rename vector as a mix between vector name and name of the df

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, vector, rename

I'm learning R so thanks you for you patiance.
First an example of my data:

```
Date <- c("23-01-19", "24-01-19", "25-01-19",  "30-01-19", "31-01-19" )
Open <- c("69.849998", "69.440002", "69.540001", "70.32", "69.559998")
High <- c("69.849998", "69.440002", "69.540001", "70.32", "69.559998")
Low <- c("69.849998", "69.440002", "69.540001", "70.32", "69.559998")
Close <- c("69.849998", "69.440002", "69.540001", "70.32", "69.559998")
Adj_Close <- c("69.849998", "69.440002", "69.540001", "70.32", "69.559998")
Volume <- c("0", "0", "0", "0","0")
InvescoDf <- data.frame(Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Adj_Close, Volume)
OssiamDf <- InvescoDf
mylist <- list(InvescoDf, OssiamDf)
```

My problem:

I managed to iterate through a list of data frames and created a new column on each calling it "Return".

```
new_list <- lapply(mylist, function(x) 
{
  x <- mutate(x, Return = (Close / lag(Close, default = first(Close)))-1)
  x
})
```

My next step would be to select all the Return vectors (8th column) and create a DF:

```
new_Df <- data.frame(sapply(new_list, function(x) x[, 8]))
```

Fine so far. But now I'd have a DF where the vector names were Return, Return1 and so on.
Is there a possibility to easily rename the vectors through an iteration in something like that?: **NameOfTheDataFrame_Return**

Thank you in advance

BR
Toni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's 'mylist' columns were all `factor` class.  So, we need to first convert the `type` with `type.convert`, use `transmute` instead of `mutate` if the intention is to return only a specific column.

The OP mentioned about name of the dataframe, which is not present in 'mylist' because it was created as unnamed

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
mylist <- lst(InvescoDf, OssiamDf) # now it is named
```

Or with the OP's code

```
names(mylist) <- c("InvescoDf", "OssiamDf")
```

In this case we can use `imap` where the `.y` returns the names of the dataset

```
imap_dfc(mylist, ~ type.convert(.x, as.is = TRUE) %>%
          transmute(!! str_c(.y, '_Return') := 
              (Close / lag(Close, default = first(Close)))-1))
#  InvescoDf_Return OssiamDf_Return
#1      0.000000000     0.000000000
#2     -0.005869664    -0.005869664
#3      0.001440078     0.001440078
#4      0.011216551     0.011216551
#5     -0.010807765    -0.010807765
```

---

In `base R`, we can do

```
out2 <- data.frame(lapply(mylist, function(dat) {
              dat <- type.convert(dat, as.is = TRUE)
              with(dat, (Close / lag(Close, default = first(Close)))-1)


       }))
names(out2) <- paste0(names(out2), "_Return")
```